# How to "attach" an ad element to centered website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

maybe this is gonna be a kinda stupid question, but if I have a centered website (using fixed width + margin: 0 auto) how do I "attach" an ad element to it? (Left skyscraper).

What i did, and do not like, is that now I have a wrapper inside which the content and ad are. But The wrapper must have bigger width than the content (page). So the website is not centered anymore and it looks really ugly when the ad is not displayed (when using adblock and stuff like that).

Is JS the only way?

Comment: I'm sure you can do it without JavaScript, but we need to see a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you.

Comment: See below, I commented and provided more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you mean by 'attach' but below is how I would structure / build it.

```
   <div id="container">
      <div class="column_left">I don't know what your using for ads, but you could place right here. Image, text, ad script?</div>
    <!-- just place your ad in the above div -->
      <div class="column_right">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
}
.column_left {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}

.column_right { 
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jkLMK/36/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I have but what I do not want. :) What I want is to keep the content centered no matter what is on the left or right side of it (skyscraper). For example, this website www.dsl.cz uses some script (maybe? cannot find it in the source) that calculates the margins of the skyscrapper (assuming from the browser's web inspector) and keeps it "glued" to the content.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused you can't use glue on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go down the script option, you can do something like this:

```
 <div id="content" style="width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;">
  ...
 </div>

 <div id="ad" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
  ...
 </div>

 <script>

  window.onresize = function() {

    var contentWidth = 960;
    var marginWidth = (window.innerWidth - contentWidth) / 2;

    document.getElementById("ad").style.width = marginWidth + "px";

  };

  window.onresize();

 </script>
```